# php curl ssl verify

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I just develop some softvare by php，use curllib to connect amazon，paypal，wechat，I want to verify cert and I find some params relate to this：

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` ： I think if you want to verify ssl cert,this param should set true；

but I am confused about `CURLOPT_CAINFO`  and

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE,'PEM');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $sslCertPath);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE,'PEM');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $sslKeyPath);
```

when should I set `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and when should i set follow 4 params?

I think `CURLOPT_CAINFO` is a param that to make sure  amazon is the amazon,paypal is the paypal;

the follow 4 params is to confirm I am the real me,amazon can confirm by these 4 params.

Am I correct?

and I don't know how to get `CURLOPT_CAINFO` ca?because I think if I confirm amazon is the amazon ,I just verify the ca that amazon send me is enough,why shoul i send a ca to amazon?

Answer (score 1):

Try it if you want to use CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . '/cacert.pem');
```

Download cacert.pem here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you receive a certificate from a website - it contains the website own certificate plus the intermediate certificate (the one that signed/issued the website's certificate). In order to verify them both, you must have a list of root certificates (CA is abbreviated from Certificate Authority) which is called "CA bundle" and usually lives at `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`. The intermediate certificate (there can be more than one intermediate certificate - each of them will/must be signed by the next one up in the chain) must be signed by a root certificate in order to be trusted.

So the purpose of `CURLOPT_CAINFO` is to allow you to specify the pathname of `ca-bundle.crt` if it can not be found automatically by cURL - or if you want to check against your custom root certificate(s).

The purpose of `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` and `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` is to present a client (as opposed to a server one) certificate so that the server can verify your identity (usually used for online banking so that you can sign your transactions) - most probably you do not need these in your use case.

The purpose of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is for you to be able to force cURL to skip verification of the server certificate - in case your CA bundle is not up to date or missing at all.

Answer (score 1):

So after downloading this cacert.pem file into your project, in PHP you can now do this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");
```

Alternatively, this can be set globally by adding the following to your php.ini

```
curl.cainfo=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

Hope this helps you.